# Constant inside If condition

Tags: simplifying-expressions, complex, conditional

I hope you are doing well.

I am currently writing some code in which I have an If statement where I will be dividing two expressions and checking to see if the quotient comes out to be a constant multiple of $i$ or not. How do I let Mathematica know that I do not care what multiple of $i$ the quotient gives?

Here is the part of my code that I am concerned about

```
 If[ min[[1]]/min[[2]]=== I, .....
```

This code performs how it is supposed to for the terms that simplifies to $1i$. If I change the code to reflect the quotient should come out to $2i$, for instance

```
If[ min[[1]]/min[[2]]=== 2I, .....
```

The code performs how it is supposed to for the terms that simplifies to $2i$.

To ask again, how could I have Mathematica check to see if the quotient is a multiple of $i$ without changing the code each time? Thank you for any assistance.

Comment: How about `Mod[quotient,I]==0` ?

Comment: If "constant multiple" means numeric, as in your examples, you could use `Re[#] == 0 && NumericQ[Im[#]] &  @  quotient`  to test the real and imaginary parts.  If you want to restrict the quotient to *integer* multiples of $i$, then use `IntegerQ` instead of `NumericQ`.  If "constant multiple" means not containing certain variables, you can use `FreeQ`.